# Prediction for one-way random effect ANOVA with rms package

Tags: r, generalized-least-squares

I'm trying to predict in the one-way random effect ANOVA model fitted with the Gls() function of the rms package. All my attempts are unsuccessful. For instance:

```
# data
set.seed(421)
I <- 3
J <- 4 
dd <- data.frame(y=rpois(I*J,10), group=gl(I,J))
# fit
library(rms)
fit <- Gls(y ~ 1, data=dd, correlation=corCompSymm(form= ~ 1 | group))
```

And then:

```
> dd
    y group
1  12     1
2  11     1
3  13     1
4  14     1
5  10     2
6   8     2
7   8     2
8  12     2
9   8     3
10  6     3
11  6     3
12  9     3
> predict(fit)
Error in predictrms(object, newdata, type, se.fit, conf.int, conf.type,  : 
  newdata not given and fit did not store x
> predict(fit,  newdata=data.frame(group="1"))
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
> Predict(fit)
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Response variable (y): 
Error in if (ci > 0) cat("\nLimits are", ci, "confidence limits\n") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

For the Predict() function the user has to specify a predictor but here there's no predictor.

Comment: @chl Thanks, but where is the on-line help please ? And here there's no predictor so I don't see which part of the data I would store.

Comment: Without having any predictors in the model there is no sense in asking for predictions.  And the `rms` package does not support intercept-only models in general.

Comment: Yup, sorry I deleted my previous comment. Type `help(Gls)` and you'll get an example using `datadist` to store predictors of interest (which is needed by `rms::Predict`) near the end of the on-line help. However, I'm afraid this question sounds off-topic and unless there's a precise statistical question behind the current one it will be closed or migrated to SO.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you. However it makes sense to predict an observation in this model, don't you agree ? See here for instance http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41177/prediction-interval-for-the-one-way-random-effect-anova

Comment: @chl Frank's comment shows that the question is statistical :)

Comment: No Stephane I do not agree.  This model has a single parameter regarding predicted means.  Its value is just a weighted mean of repeated responses.  As I said before if there are no predictors in a model it is hard to see why you would want predictions.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Here we can define a predicted observation similarly to the simple Gaussian sample model, as in Lin & Liao's paper. Now imagine a bigger model : there are two "big" groups A and B of three individuals, and each individual of each group has repeated mesures. Thus the group is a predictor and for each group we have exactly the model of my OP. Do you claim that it makes sense to predict for this model because there is a predictor ? Why would we can predict for each group when we have two groups but we couldn't predict when we have a single group only ?

Comment: @FrankHarrell And the prediction I'm talking about is compatible with the predictive distribution in the sense of the Bayesian perspective.

Comment: @FrankHarrell In fact there's a predictor with one level only. Models with predictors in your sense are models with predictors taking at least two values/levels.

Comment: Correct.  I.e., the model has a predictor in it (group), unlike your model.  You are not using group in the mean part of the model, only in the correlation structure.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes I said "big group" to distinguish from the "group" of my OP. So I don't understand your logic: if I have two big groups I can predict in each of them, but not if I have only one.

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46755/getting-the-good-prediction-standard-error-with-r-and-or-sas

Comment: I am commenting only on your OP.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Ok, thank you. Maybe you could convert your main comment to an answer ? All the best, Stéphane.