# Getting the good prediction standard error with R and/or SAS

Tags: r, mixed-model, sas, prediction

Consider for instance the balanced one-way random effects ANOVA model:
$$(y_{ij} \mid \mu_i) \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu_i, \sigma^2_w), \quad j=1,\ldots,J, 
\qquad 
\mu_i \sim {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2_b), \quad i=1,\ldots,I. $$

In [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41177/prediction-interval-for-the-one-way-random-effect-anova) I asked how to get a prediction interval and I found an answer in a published paper by Lin & Liao. The approach is similar to the case of the simple Gaussian sample model and it runs as follows. Denote by $\sigma_{\textrm{tot}}^2=\sigma^2_b+\sigma^2_w$  the total variance and by 
$\tau^2=\sigma^2_b+\frac{\sigma^2_w}{J}$ the variance of the sample mean $\bar{y}_{i\bullet}$. Then, considering a new observation $y^{\textrm{new}}$ one has $$
y^{\textrm{new}} - \bar{y}_{\bullet\bullet} \sim 
{\cal N}\left(0, \sigma^2_{\textrm{tot}} + \frac{\tau^2}{I}\right).$$ 
The variance can also be written as 
 $$  \left(1+\frac{1}{I}\right)\tau^2 + \left(1-\frac{1}{J}\right)\sigma^2_w$$ and it is estimated without bias by $\frac{I+1}{I(I-1)}\frac{SS_b}{J} + \frac{SS_w}{IJ}$ where $SS_b$ is the between sum of squares and $SS_w$ is the within sum of squares. Moreover $SS_w$, $SS_b$, $y^{\textrm{new}}$ and $\bar{y}_{\bullet\bullet}$ are independent. Then we have the distributional approximation
$$\frac{y^{\textrm{new}} - \bar{y}_{\bullet\bullet}}{\sqrt{\frac{I+1}{I(I-1)}\frac{SS_b}{J} + \frac{SS_w}{IJ}}} \approx \mathrm{t}_\nu,$$ where $\nu$ are the Satterthwaite degrees of freedom.

Now I wonder whether it is possible to get the prediction standard error (or alternatively an approximation) $se=\sqrt{\frac{I+1}{I(I-1)}\frac{SS_b}{J} + \frac{SS_w}{IJ}}$ with R and/or SAS. I am not only interested in this example, but also in more general mixed models.

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46644/prediction-for-one-way-random-effect-anova-with-rms-package) I asked whether it is possible with Frank Harrell's `Gls` package but the author himself replies that this package does not handle predictions for a model "without predictor".

Below is a numerical example for the balanced one-way random effect ANOVA:

```
ranovapred <- function(y, group, conf=0.95){
    group <- factor(group)
    means <- aggregate(y~group, FUN=mean)$y  # groups means
    I <- length(levels(group))
    J <- length(y)/I
    sizes <- table(group) # groups sizes
    if(!all(as.numeric(sizes)==J)){ stop("balanced only!") }
    ssw <- crossprod(y-rep(means, times=sizes))  # within sum of squares
    ssb <- J*crossprod(means-mean(y)) # beween sum of squares
    a <- (1/J*(1+1/I))/(I-1)
    b <- 1/I/J 
    v <- a*ssb+b*ssw # estimates the variance of (Ynew-Ybar)
    nu <- v^2/((a*ssb)^2/(I-1)+(b*ssw)^2/I/(J-1)) # Satterthwaite degrees of freedom
    alpha <- 1-conf
    bounds <- mean(y) + c(-1,1)*sqrt(v)*qt(1-alpha/2,nu)
return(list(bounds=bounds, std.error=sqrt(v), ss=c(ssw=ssw,ssb=ssb)) )
}
# fictive data
set.seed(421)
I <- 3
J <- 4 
dd <- data.frame(y=rpois(I*J,10), group=gl(I,J))

> dd
    y group
1  12     1
2  11     1
3  13     1
4  14     1
5  10     2
6   8     2
7   8     2
8  12     2
9   8     3
10  6     3
11  6     3
12  9     3
> ranovapred(y=dd$y,dd$group)
$bounds
[1] -1.136421 20.636421

$std.error
         [,1]
[1,] 3.338538

$ss
  ssw   ssb 
22.75 55.50
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with SAS for the above example.

```
DATA DD;
    INPUT y group $;
    DATALINES;
    12 A
    11 A
    13 A
    14 A
    10 B
    8 B
    8 B 
    12 B
    8 C
    6 C
    6 C
    9 C
;

PROC MIXED DATA=DD;
    CLASS group;
    MODEL y= / s ;
    RANDOM group / V ;
RUN;
QUIT;
```

The estimate of $\sigma^2_{\textrm{tot}}$ is given in the diagonal entries of the $V$ matrix (this is the estimate of the variance matrix of the marginal model). The estimate of the variance of $\bar{y}_{\bullet\bullet}$ is the square of the standard error of the intercept. Then summing these two estimates and taking the square root give the prediction standard error.

Now what about R ? I remember that is possible to get the $V$ matrix with the `lme()` function of the `nlme` package. Is it possible to get it with the `lmer()` function of the `lme4` package ?

Comment: Maybe this is relevant (I'm not sure, this is all above my pay grade), https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/109308.html